# Unable to login in SQL Server 2008 R2 64 bit from SQL Server 2008 R2 32 bit

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, database-replication, merge-replication

I have a Windows Server 64 bit and I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on it. I'm intending to use this machine for data replication. So, I have clients with Windows 7 32 bit on which I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2.

I want to create a publication on the Server (64bit) and subscribers (32 bit). I've enabled remote connections, disabled firewall, enabled named pipes and TCP, Telnet. I'm able to login to SQL Server (64 bit) from subscribers (32 bit) BUT I am unable to login to the server from subscribers.

Any help is highly appreciated.